# Failure on the handshake while calling https

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, postman, keytool, jks

I need your help here on calling HTTPS rest service.

Some background, 
I need to call a rest service hosted as HTTPS.

I got the certificate and I managed to get a response from Postman.
Very important, I could only connect when I declared on Postman the certificate as a '**ca certificate**' if I declared it as '**client certificate**' I could not connect.

Now I wanted to call the service through java so I generate JKS by keytool:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias PublicKeyFromCEF -file service.cer -keystore ABCD.jks

I built a client

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:/ABCD.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "123456");
Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

char[] passphrase = "123456".toCharArray(); //password
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
//KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(new FileInputStream("c:/ABCD.jks"), passphrase); //path

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keystore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
URL url = new URL("https://services/api/v1/doctors?docId=5555");

HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpsCon.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
httpsCon.setRequestMethod("GET");

System.out.println("Response Message is " + httpsCon.getResponseMessage());
```

When I call the service I get the error: **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** in method `java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead`

**I suspect that I did not generate the JKS correctly**

Here are the objects state on debug, I hope it shed a light:

in method `sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl#performInitialHandshake` :

```
this.input.r.helloVersion = LTSv1
```

`this.input.r.getHandshakeHash() : mds,sha are null, data is populated.`

in method: `sun.security.ssl.InputRecord#read`

```
this.exlen =0
```

then I get an exception on `java.net.SocketInputStream#tRead` when calling  `n = socketRead(fd, b, off, length, timeout);`